# Get most frequent value and std based on precentile data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

This half of a statisctical question actually,

I have a dataframe consisting of 9-columns. each one indicates a different diameter of an apple based on several measurements. the rows are the precentage:

```
     55      60      65       70       75       80      85      90      95
0    0.0,   0.0     10.73   39.13      8.35    8.63     33.16   0.0     0.0
1    3.42   0.0     1.28    26.09      31.3   26.73     8.07    3.11    0.0
```

I am trying to plot some kind distibution plot while getting the average diameter of an apple with an STD. can't really think of a good way myself. any ideas?

edit:

barplot produces a nice chart but I want to be able to get the most frequent value, and standart deviation.

```
b=sns.barplot(data=df)
```

[image: barplot]

I Tried using mode but it does not work.

```
df.mode()
```

Comment: could you please share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This is the routine I use for mode calc, maybe it will be useful for you, too. Be aware that it looks for the mode in a range (mean-shift, mean+shift), so won't work for very skewed distributions (the tolerance defined by *shift*).

```
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
def get_mode(s0: pd.Series):
    """Get mode from non-parametric Gaussian fit."""
    # Non-parametric pdf.
    s = s0.copy()
    mean = s.mean()
    shift = 20
    lower, upper = mean - shift, mean + shift
    x = np.linspace(lower, upper, 250)
    # Cut-off the upper and lower margins.
    s = s.dropna()[(s < upper) & (s > lower)]
    try:
        nparam_density = gaussian_kde(s.ravel())
    except ValueError:
        # Not enough data: return mean.
        return mean
    nparam_density_vec = nparam_density(x)

    max_hist = x[nparam_density_vec.argmax()]
    return max_hist
```